# Solve $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-2\pi i\langle\eta,x\rangle}e^{-a|\eta|}d\eta$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, fourier-analysis

How to calculate $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-2\pi i\langle\eta,x\rangle}e^{-a|\eta|}d\eta$$ where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the canonical inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'm trying use contour integral for this, but I don't know what curves it's the right.

The deal is to calculate a Fourier Transform.

Comment: This isn't an answer by any means but it may help. In one variable, the answer (up to a multiplicative factor) is $\dfrac{1}{a}\dfrac{1}{1+\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2}$.

Comment: Thanks, Cameron, I have solved for one dimension, but I'm having difficult for to generalize.